# Finding order statistic of i.i.d. uniform random variables (distribution of middle value)

Tags: probability

Consider three independent uniformly distributed (taking values between $0$ and $1$) random variables. What is the probability that the middle of the three values (between the lowest and the highest value) lies between $a$ and $b$ where $0 ≤ a < b ≤ 1$?

A) $3 (1 - b) a (b - a)$

B) $3 ((b - a) - (b^{2}- a^{2})/2)$

C) $6 (1 - b) a (b - a)$

D) $(1 - b) a (b - a)$

E) $6 ((b^{2}- a^{2})/ 2 - (b^{3} - a^{3})/3)$.

---

Now, formula for uniform distribution $\int_{a}^{b} xdx=\left [ \frac{x^{2}}{2} \right ]_{a}^{b}$

According to the question middle value of $3$ values are inside $a$ and $b.$

So, here can be 4 possibilities. Say numbers are x,y,z.

Now,

Case $1:$ Only $y$ can be inside $a$ and $b.$

Case $2:$ Only $x,y$ can be inside $a$ and $b.$

Case $3:$ Only $y,z$ can be inside $a$ and $b.$

Case $4:$  $x,y,z$ all can be inside $a$ and $b.$

So, probability should be $\frac{\frac{^{4}\textrm{C}_{1}\times \left ( b^{2}-a^{2} \right )}{2}}{\frac{^{8}\textrm{C}_{1}\times \left ( b^{2}-a^{2} \right )}{2}}$

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I’m not sure I fully understand everything you’re saying above, but if you want to model the distribution of the second largest value, you’re gonna want to get the second order statistic. Then if $F$ is the CDF of the second order statistic, the probability of being between $b$ and $a$ is just $F(b)-F(a)$. Really makes things a lot simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can answer this question using order statistics.

From Wackerley, Mendenhall, and Schaeffer's Mathematical Statistics with Applications:

> Let $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ be independent identically-distributed continuous random variables with common distribution function $F(y)$ and common density function $f(y)$. If $Y_{(k)}$ denotes the $k$th-order statistic, then the density function of $Y_{(k)}$ is given by
>   $$g_{(k)}(y_k) = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} \left[F(y_k)\right]^{k-1} \left[1-F(y_k)\right]^{n-k} f(y_k)$$

In this case, let $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3\sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$ be the three i.i.d. random variables uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$, and hence we have p.d.f. $f(y) = 1$ for $y\in [0,1]$, and C.D.F. $F(y) = y$ for $y\in [0,1)$ and $F(y) = 1$ for $y>1$.

Plugging these into the above identity, and setting $k=2$ as we intend to find the second order statistic (the distribution of the middle value), we get

\begin{align}
g_{(2)}(y_2) &= \frac{3!}{(2-1)!(3-2)!} y_2^{2-1} (1-y_2)^{3-2} (1)\\
&=6 y_2(1-y_2)\\
&= -6y_2^2 + 6y_2 
\end{align}

Then the probability that $Y_{(2)}$ lies between $a$ and $b$ is given by

\begin{align}
\int_a^b g_{(2)}(y_2)\,dy_2 &= \int_a^b (-6y_2^2 + 6y_2) \,dy_2\\
&= \left[-2y_2^3 + 3y_2^2 \right]_a^b\\
&= 2a^3 - 3a^2 -2b^3 +3b^2\\
&=6((b^2−a^2)/2−(b^3−a^3)/3)
\end{align}

So the answer to your question is $(E)$.

---

*Oh*, and another thing that's worth pointing out:

- In particular, if you're ever getting the order statistics over an i.i.d. sequence of uniformly distributed random variables over an interval $(0, 1)$, the $k$th-order statistic based on a sample size $n$ has a Beta distribution with parameters $\alpha=k$ and $\beta=n-k+1$. In this case, $Y_{(2)} \sim Beta(2,2)$, since our sample size was $n=3$ and we wanted the $k=2$ order statistic so we have $\alpha=2$ and $\beta=3-2+1=2$. This gives us an easier way of jumping directly to the p.d.f. or C.D.F. of the already well-understood Beta distribution.

Comment: Any reference?? I have not seen this formula before :(

Comment: Besides for Wackerly, Mendenhall, and Schaeffer’s Mathematical Statistics with Applications? I also found it here: https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/314/, and perhaps this might help: https://youtu.be/2LR5JYbhyjg (around the 30 minute mark).

Comment: Basically, if I have $n$ i.i.d. random variables, the $k$th order statistic is just the $k$th smallest of those values in order. In this case, when we have $3$ random variables, the second order statistic is just “the middle one”! You basically need order statistics whenever dealing with questions about “the distribution of the middle value” or “the maximum value” or “the minimum value” or “the xth largest value” or whatever. They’re super useful!